# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, blob

I am using a simple interface (in jsf 1.2 and rich faces 3.3.2, Oracle 11g R1) to let user select picture with rich:fileUpload and save in a table.
As a test, i created following table.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
 MIME_TYPE VARCHAR2 (1000),
 PHOTO BLOB,
 STUDENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
)
```

code snippet to save the picture to BLOB field is as follows.

```
//......From the uploadFile Listener
public void listener(UploadEvent event) throws Exception {
...      
item = event.getUploadItem();
...
StudentPhotoDAO dao = new StudentPhotoDAO();
dao.storePhoto(item.getData(),item.getContentType(),studentId);
...
}


//......From the PhotoDAO ..........................


public void storePhoto(byte data[],String mimeType, Long studentId){
{
 ...
  ByteArrayInputStream bis=new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
  String query = "update  TEST set PHOTO = ? ,MIME_TYPE = ?  where STUDENT_ID=?";
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  pstmt.setAsciiStream(1,(InputStream)bis,data.length);
  pstmt.setString(2,mimeType.toString());
  pstmt.setLong(3,studentId);
  pstmt.executeUpdate();
 }
```

I get following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Where is the error in the code please.

Thanks.

Comment: It appears the SQL type NUMBER is not compatible with the Java type Long.

Comment: In Oracle, LONG is a textual type, not a numeric type. Most of these answers are looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

You specify the `student_id` as `number`, which seems to map to `BigInteger`. See e.g. [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm).

Either you supply a `BigInteger` or you need to change the type of `student_id`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i did convert student_id to BigInteger. but how to map it to preparedStatement argument. since there is no pstmt.setBigInteger method...

Comment: Used this but same error BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(studentId.longValue());
String query = "Update TEST SET PHOTO = ? , MIME_TYPE = ? where STUDENT_ID=" + bi + "";

Comment: Try to set it using `setObject()` instead

Comment: sir can you put in some code how to use setObject() (i m a beginner here)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Oracle LONG type description](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/LONG):
"LONG is an Oracle data type for storing character data ...". So LONG is not number in Oracle. It's a text.

I think you got this error because of this:
`pstmt.setAsciiStream(1,(InputStream)bis,data.length);`

Try use `pstmt.setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, int)` or `pstmt.setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, long)`.

Comment: pstmt.setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, int) throws the same exception when data is more than 4000 bytes

Comment: @AjaySharma, [sscce](http://sscce.org/) proofs plz. I can not reproduce it in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
pstmt.setLong(3,studentId);
```

and you specified column as

```
STUDENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
```

and how docs says:

> An attempt was made to insert a value from a LONG datatype into
>   another datatype. This is not allowed.

So just make it like this:

```
STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
pstmt.setInt(3, studentId);
```

Comment: cant changed the column from NUMBER. (its some compulsion which i can tell you but then i ll ve to *ill you ;) ).

Comment: The INTEGER oracle datatype is equivalent to NUMBER(28)

Comment: [Oracle's `LONG` type is a character data type](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020). The problem here is related to the first bind value, not the third...

Answer (score 0):

When binding large binary streams to a BLOB column in Oracle, use `PreparedStatement.setBlob()` rather than `setAsciiStream()` or `setBinaryStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using ASCII stream is to blame.

```
pstmt.setAsciiStream(1, (InputStream) bis, data.length);
```

Try

```
pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

(It looks like Oracle interprets ASCII stream with length parameters as LONG which cannot be more than 4000 bytes. But that's only an unconfirmed guess.)