# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.1.0 in an update: ORA-01461: CAN BIND A LONG VALUE ONLY FOR INSERT INTO A LONG COLUMN

Tags: oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have this error when doing an update of a table:

```
ORA-01461: CAN BIND A LONG VALUE ONLY FOR INSERT INTO A LONG COLUMN
```

the column that gives this error is defined as a `CLOB` and I am trying to insert a string with nearly 40k characters...
I read [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3649551) that a solution would be to define the `ParameterDirection` as `InputOutput` and not only `Input`. I did but then I get the following error

```
ORA-00932: INCOHERENT TYPES OF DATA: - WAITED; CLOB OBTAINED
```

How can I solve this problem? Also I think is a problem of the dll because with `System.Data.OracleClient` it works well. But I would like to use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` because the other one is deprecated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156019/ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-long-column-occurs-when
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393786/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-l
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792472/error-while-updating-a-table-with-clob-columnora-01461 Uncle Google is always willing to help :)

Comment: I tried declare large_string clob := rpad('c',32760,'c');
  begin
  update test_clob set clob_col = nvl(large_string,clob_col) where id1 =1;
  commit;
  end; but it gives me ORA-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Answer (score 0):

https://community.oracle.com/thread/509725?start=15&tstart=0

Again - paste this error in Google - many people have many errors, and this problems often repeated.

Comment: i have googled it before.. but i couldn't find a solution that worked.. otherwise i wouldn't have asked..

Comment: I red that this error is caused by too much data in value. 
You have 40000 characters and as You know, Oracle can hold in single value up to 32k